# Will Google value links to expired domains that have been down for months if I create a new site there?

Tags: seo, google, links, expired-domains

I found some new dropped domains that I buy that have decent links that are all 404 of course. When a domain is dropped and the link has been 404'd for over 100 days does Google 100% ignore that domain or does it respect it again when it comes back online?

Answer (score 2):

The expired domains can power a real business. I've launched sites on more than 400 of them.  If you want to take advantage of those "lost" back links, you should do these best practice first:

- Recover the same content on the same URL
- Create new content in the same subject on the same URL
- Create new content about the same subject on other internal URLs but make a redirect

Other ways may not work.
For example, this won't work for the back links pointing to the home page.